# Изменить порядок слов Python

Tags: python, порядок

Всем привет! Есть ли библиотека Python, которая меняет порядок слов в предложении? Например у меня есть предложение:

```
21ис-3 1) Математика 211кб Панфилова
```

И при помощи библиотеки можно было бы получить

```
21ис-3
1) 211кб Математика Панфилова
```

Ну или по другому,как уже захочу я

Comment: Для этого не надо никакой библиотеки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txt = '21ис-3 1) Математика 211кб Панфилова И'
tt = txt.split()
print(tt)
print(f'{tt[1]} {tt[3]} {tt[2]} {tt[4]}')

['21ис-3', '1)', 'Математика', '211кб', 'Панфилова', 'И']
1) 211кб Математика Панфилова
```

Comment: Сплит по пробельным символам дефолтный, можно параметр не указывать